# Overflow hidden added to front page of wordpress site

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm a little new to Wordpress, and I'm using one of the default theme. Something in the theme is adding overflow hidden tags directly to the html and body elements of the front page so that it doesn't scroll. They're not hardcoded in the templates, so it seems some JS is adding those styles suddenly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://sharesleuth.com/wordpress/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the built in javascript for the document viewer you are using in [this post](http://sharesleuth.com/wordpress/short-takes/2011/10/penny_stock_promoter_gets_deep) which appears to be [this one](https://github.com/NYTimes/document-viewer). Either remove the document viewer altogether or see if you can figure out the problem with the javascript. It looks like it isn't being contained properly and therefore applying the `overflow` to the wrong parent (the window `body` and html `tags`)

Comment: It seems Doc Cloud pushed out an update that caused all kind of problems.